# Align spatial data that is to the left of a global dataset in QGIS, even though their CRS is the same

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have downloaded a Version 2 CCMP Wind Product raster that is global in scale, and am trying to align it with a shapefile polygon of Canada and Greenland's administrative boundaries. Both datasets have the same CRS, and should line up just fine. However, because the CCMP raster depicts the world as a rectangle, it splits western Africa in half, with the majority of Africa on the left (west), and the rest of it on the right (east). As a result, Canada and Greenland appear to the west of the raster, where Canada and Greenland would be if the raster wasn't split in half at Africa. A screenshot of this is attached. How do I deal with this? I can't reproject the data because it's already in the same CRS. I am using QGIS 3.10.12, no access to commercial software [image]

Comment: I guess your raster is from an American source and thus uses a CRS which doesn't split at 180°.

Comment: That is correct. Are there any workarounds, or will I need to find new data?

Comment: I think there are specific CRS for this kind of data, but that is hear-say.

Comment: As in I reproject the raster to that CRS, or the shapefile?